# How do i use GtkGLArea in GTK+#?

Tags: c#, opengl, gtk

I am trying to use GTK in C# and the instructions I found on how to use GtkGLArea are for C/C++ but I cannot seem to find all of the methods and classes in the C# library.
I found the GLArea widget class, but I cannot seem to find any way to actually use OpenGL.

Are there any builtin OpenGL bindings or do I need to use an external OpenGL library? If so, how do i tie the library to the GLArea widget?